# Page is not scrolling while data is binding in windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am working in the windows phone 7 app development . I am implementing the couple of pages like Dashboard and Friends list, Chat list in the App.

After loading the page i am calling the updates of dashboard, friends and chat list of relevant page and binding those results. For this process it is taking some time due to huge data. During the process if i scroll the page ,it is not scrolling.

During the loading if we click on the any other control of the page also is not working.

Please suggest any solution?

Thanks&Regards
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in advance for a general answer but your question isn't very specific.

The things that are most likely causing your issue are:
 - Lots of activity happening on the UI thread which shouldn't/needn't
 - Loading more items at a time than is necessary
 - Not using a virtualised list when it may have been appropriate to do so